# Change column type to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my form and it gets its source from a DataTable. Would there be a way to change the column type to a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn after setting the source or would I have to insert each row and its cell separately and perform the change then

Previous code:

```
Select("uspSelectChildByClientID", 
    new string[] { "clientID" }, new string[] { nodeTag.ToString() });
dataGridViewC.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Intended code (if there's really no way to change it after getting the source):

```
Select("uspSelectChildByClientID", new string[] { "clientID" }, 
    new string[] { nodeTag.ToString() });
for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Columns.Count; x++)
     dataGridViewC.Columns.Add("hello", dataTable.Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString());
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
*add checkbox column and make another loop*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, relying on `DataSource` and `Columns.Insert()` at the same time in `DataGridView` is not precisely recommendable. Although when dealing with special column types (like `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`), this approach does deliver a quite good answer. Further modifications at the cell level might even not be required. Sample code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col 1", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(1);
dt.Rows.Add(2);
dt.Rows.Add(3);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn curCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
curCol.HeaderText = "Col 2";
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, curCol);
```